# How to customise invitation card with people names?

Tags: libreoffice, gimp, scribus

My question is very large, and I'm not sure if I should have put it here or on super-user, or else where, but I ask here as I'm using Ubuntu :)

It happen frequently that I need to create various variant of the same asset, with a base template and only a few difference in text. I always find it troublesome and error prone to do it manually, and each time, as a developer used to automation, I wonder if there would not be a way to automate that.

I am completely open to the tooling as long as it can generate something usable (pdf, png, html, odt, whatever...).

My current use case is to create 100 invitation card for a birthday party, with the name of each participant at the top of card (Dear XXX, you are invited to celebrate my birthday blah blah blah...).

I know how to customize text like that with spreadsheets by using a template in a cell and doing replace(), but even then I would just have "cells" in a single document, and I would not know how to export them automatically in single documents with a full layout.

I'm quite sure some software is able to do that, it is a use case so common it is not possible every body does it by hand everywhere in the world :)

Any clue ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `gLabels` for this purpose.

Its downloadable from Ubuntu Software.

I use it on 20.04 LTS and I have also downloaded it for use on my 22.04 LTS scratch system.

It is a very easy tool to use for generating labels of all description, address labels and the like, and I have found it very much more usable and intuitive than `Libre Office` for this purpose.

[image]

> It is designed to work with various laser/ink-jet peel-off label and
> business card sheets that you'll find at most office supply stores.
>
> gLabels can be used to design address labels, name tags, price tags,
> cd/dvd labels, or just about anything else that is organized in a
> regular pattern on a sheet of paper. Labels (or cards) can contain
> text, images, lines, shapes, and barcodes. gLabels also includes a
> document-merge feature which lets you print a unique label for each
> record from an external data source, such as a CSV file or an
> Evolution address book.